# Is it possible to display the address location on pin with out tap on pin?

Tags: iphone, maps, latitude-longitude, pins

In my application i have one requirement.i have the latitude and longitude values on cell in table view. when user tap on cell then automatically display the info(location address ) on pin(which pin is having the latitude and longitude values same as cell from table ). i am displaying the tableView and mapView in single view only in ipad.

Answer (score 1):

when u add the pin, for your MKAnnotationView set `annotationView.setSelected = YES;`
this will enable the annotation view to display a callout bubble automatically

Comment: when i select the cell automatically info will be displayed on pin.cell is have the latitude longitude of that pin.In map i have 100's of pins.

Comment: you can do this with only a single pin. if u want to do this for more than one pin, you need to make a custom view with label instead of using native pin

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.What you are looking for is adding Annotation to the mapview
A good [tutorial here](http://maybelost.com/2011/01/a-basic-mapview-and-annotation-tutorial/)

Comment: :Thanks for immediate response.i already added the annotation to the map.my requirement is how can i display the info on pin when user click on cell.cell is having the info abot the pin.u